# Image animation not getting displayed

Tags: java, animation, awt, frame, paint

I have the following code.I want to display the images in my **chick** array on the screen after **some time delay**.The coordinates have to be shifted by **10px each x direction** when the new 
 image is loaded.I would like to know what additional code snippets can i add in this code to have an animation on my Frame with the two images i have .Below is my code:

```java
 import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Frame;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;


    public class Chicken extends Frame implements Runnable{
        Thread animation;
        long frameDelay = 3000;
        Image chick[] = new Image[2];
        int numFrames = chick.length;
        Toolkit tk = getToolkit();
        public Chicken()
        {
            setSize(new Dimension(300,300));
            setVisible(true);
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            animation = new Thread(this);
            chick[0] = tk.createImage("stand.png");
            chick[1] = tk.createImage("walk.png");
            animation.start();
            //setVisible(false);

        }
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawImage(chick[0],100,100,null );
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(frameDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Chicken instance = new Chicken();
        }

    }
```

Comment: While there are some obvious issues with your approach, what is your particular problem??

Comment: Well,for the starters i intend to display the first image on  my applet but my applet doesnt seem to show any image.

Comment: I assume you know that you've not shown code for an applet...

Comment: I think the OP means the Frame.

Comment: @JohnSnow Yes i mean my Frame

Comment: Where are the images stored...?

Comment: @MadProgrammer In the default package in my workspace under my Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first problem you have is a resource issue.

Resources stored "within" the application (typically known as embedded resources) can't be loaded like external resources.

```
chick[0] = tk.createImage("stand.png");
```

Is expecting a file `"./stand.png"` which doesn't exist.  Instead, you need to load the resource through the `Class#getResource` API...

```
chick[0] = tk.createImage(getClass().getResource("/stand.png"));
```

The second problem you will face is the fact that you are overriding `paint` of a top level container.  This really shouldn't be done.  Let's start with the fact it's not double buffered and end with the fact that frames have decorations which sit inside the viewable area.  This means that the decorations will overlap what ever you paint to the surface...not pretty...

The third problem is you are not telling the image where it should move to.  It's static.

You need some kind of x/y value that tells the image where it should be painted.  You would modify these values by a given x/y delta within you thread before you called `repaint`...

The forth problem you might have is the fact that you are using AWT...which is kind of dated.  Swing would solve your double buffering issue for you...IMHO, would make a better choice - there's a lot more documentation and examples on Swing laying around now days ;)

While I'm on my hobble horse...I would, personally, recommend [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) over `Toolkit#createImage` or `ImageIcon`, mostly because it supports more formats, but also because it will throw an `Exception` when the image can't be read for some reason...

I have a simple example if Swing, but I won't post it, because I'll get in trouble for running of topic...let me know if you would like to see it

**Updated with Swing example**

This uses a embedded image in the default package...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ChickenDance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChickenDance();
    }

    public ChickenDance() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage chicken;
        private int xPos;
        private int yPos;

        private int xDelta = 4;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                chicken = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Chicken.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ChickenDance.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    xPos += xDelta;
                    if (xPos + chicken.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                        xPos = getWidth() - chicken.getWidth();
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    } else if (xPos < 0) {
                        xPos = 0;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    yPos = (getHeight() - chicken.getHeight()) / 2;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            if (chicken != null) {
                timer.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (chicken != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.drawImage(chicken, xPos, yPos, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: and the 5th problem is the current animation frame should be maintained during the animation to be able to change images

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanx for the great answer and i would definitely like to view your swing example!!